# JFreeChart - CategoryAxis step

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a method for generating dataset:

```
private CategoryDataset createDataset(double[] arr,
            String seriesName) {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            dataset.addValue(arr[i], "mySeries", new Integer(i));
        }

        return dataset;
    }
```

and create BarChart:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(chartTitle,
                xaxis, // domain axis label
                yaxis, // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                orientation, // orientation
                true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips?
                false // URLs?
                );
```

Array of doubles hold histogram data, so there are 255 values.

When I display chart there are labels for
all values from 0 - 255 on x axis. I want display only labels for several indexes  (for example: 0, 10, 20, 30). I saw that in RangeAxis there is setStandardTickUnits method. But in CategoryAxis:

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
```

I didn't find this.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows，

```
NumberAxis vn = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();   
vn.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10d)); 
vn.setRange(0D, Math.ceil(factor * MAX_VALUE));
```

--that is you just need cast `plot.getRangeAxis()` to NumberAxis type.

Comment: Isn't this the y axis?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I created new class implementing 'Comparable', and use it as last parameter in addValue(...). You can create something like

```
class MyCategory implements Comparable<MyCategory> {
   Integer value;
   String stValue;

   MyCategory(int val) {
      value = val; 
      stValue = val%10==0?""+val:"";}

   public int compareTo(MyCategory key) { return value.compareTo(key.value); }

   public String toString() { return stValue; }
}
```

And then instead of

```
dataset.addValue(arr[i], "mySeries", new Integer(i));
```

use

```
dataset.addValue(arr[i], "mySeries", new MyCategory(i));
```